# Error while trying to use Curve Modifier - Cannot apply modifier for this object type

Tags: modeling

I was trying to use a curve modifier on some text. Everything works fine until I try to apply the modifier. I'm not sure whether I'm doing something wrong. Can someone be kind enough and give it a quick look please.

[image: 1]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the text to a Mesh object.

**Object -> Convert to -> Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text**

Comment: It worked.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is there are vertical edges missing. Two options:
1) Make straight letters moved by equal distance from center
2) If curved letters is what you need - you need to create a surface, divide it couple of times, than create letters, convert text from curves to mesh. Project mesh letters on a surface. Cut out the rest (faces), than apply curve modifier.